# How to enable HTTPS with certobot/letsencrypt on Amazon Linux 2 with nginx

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, lets-encrypt, certbot, amazon-linux-2

Install certbot/letsencrypt on Amazon Linux 2 and enable HTTPS on nginx (similar process available for apache)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### Install certbot

```
sudo yum update
sudo yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
sudo yum-config-manager --enable epel
sudo yum install certbot python3-certbot-nginx
certbot --version
```

---

### Generate certification

Use the following command to generate the certification and automatic let the certbot to modify the nginx configuration to enable https:

```
sudo certbot --nginx
```

or if you need only the certification, use the following command:

```
sudo certbot certonly --nginx
```

The certification will be created on the folder

> /etc/letsencrypt/live/*YOUR_SITE_NAME*/

for example:

Certification

> /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.my-site.com/cert.pem

Private key

> /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.my-site.com/privkey.pem

---

### Enable automatic renewal

Use the following command to enable automatic renewal of the certification:

```
sudo certbot renew --dry-run
```

---

### Errors i have encourred

If during certification creation an error like the following appears:

> "Could not choose appropriate plugin: The requested nginx plugin does
> not appear to be installed"

then run the command

```
sudo yum install certbot python-certbot-nginx
```

and retry to create the certification.

### Notes

For apache, you can use `python2-certbot-apache` instad of `python2-certbot-nginx`,
make sure your using the option `--apache` instead of `--nginx` during the creation of the certification.

DNS must be configured to point to your macchine, othrewise the check of the certbot will fails.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful. I could not find `python3-certbot-nginx` but only `python2-certbot-nginx`. I think that needs to be changed in the first code block above. Some instructions for installing automatic renewal would be great.

Comment: This does not work with Amazon Linux 2023. I get an error when trying to install epel: Error: 
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides redhat-release >= 7 needed by epel-release-7-14.noarch

Comment: @MattHovey just in case you feel lonely, I am currently dealing with the exact same issue.

Comment: @MattHovey this guide works only with Amazon Linux 2, if you're using Amazon Linux 2023 please take a look into this [discussion](https://repost.aws/questions/QUIMw8IWHSQz6W5tGv3WO1qA/problem-conflicting-requests-nothing-provides-redhat-release-7-needed-by-epel-release-7-14-noarch?sc_ichannel=ha&sc_ilang=en&sc_isite=repost&sc_iplace=hp&sc_icontent=QUIMw8IWHSQz6W5tGv3WO1qA&sc_ipos=18) on aws.
TLDR; You can follow the official certbot pip instructions [here](https://certbot.eff.org/instructions?ws=nginx&os=pip), just tested looks working fine.

Comment: From the aws documentation: [Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux (EPEL) is a project in the Fedora community with the objective of creating a large array of packages for enterprise-level Linux operating systems. The project has primarily produced RHEL and CentOS packages. Amazon Linux 2 features a high level of compatibility with CentOS 7. As a result, many EPEL7 packages work on Amazon Linux 2. However, AL2023 doesn't support EPEL or EPEL-like repositories.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/linux/al2023/ug/compare-with-al2.html#epel)

Answer (score 7):

In July 2023, Amazon Linux 2 Doesn't support epel repos. You can however use the python package if you're able to ssh into the machine.

Like so:

```bash
sudo pip3 install certbot certbot-nginx

# then execute
sudo /usr/local/bin/certbot --nginx -d ilovetoast.com www.ilovetoast.com
```

references:

- [aws epel bs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/linux/al2023/ug/compare-with-al2.html#epel)
- [sourced commands](http://howto.philippkeller.com/2022/05/04/How-to-install-letsencrypt-for-nginx-on-Amazon-Linux-2/)

Answer (score -1):

You can secure an AWS EC2 instance with Let's Encrypt SSL certificates by following the steps outlined in this informative Medium article: [How to Secure the AWS EC2 Instance with Let's Encrypt SSL Certificates](https://medium.com/@geeekfa/how-to-secure-the-aws-ec2-instance-with-lets-encrypt-ssl-certificates-42f82c9d58b0).

In summary, the article provides a detailed guide on setting up SSL certificates using Let's Encrypt on an AWS EC2 instance, ensuring the security of your web application.

Please refer to the article for step-by-step instructions and additional insights on this topic.